# Unable to import video files to flowblade

Tags: video, codecs, video-conversion

I'm using flowblade 0.8 and I can't import video files of any kind. I had this problem before and it was solved by installing some codecs.

Unfortunately I forgot to take a note of which packeges needed to be installed.

Does anyone know which package could be missing? I think they were in the regular Ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 3):

[This site](https://code.google.com/p/flowblade/wiki/DependenciesList) contains a list of important dependencies.

Actually the package `libmlt-data` was the only one missing in my case - installing that fixed the problem